# How to compare input type to a particular column in database

Tags: php

I have an input type name="name" and when I submit it I want to check if it matches any data in a particular column in the database called"name" (seen in the picture) and if it matches, I will execute a certain command. My problem is I don't know the proper query or logic if my input matches any data in that particular column. I tried this code but it's not giving me correct output. Thanks in advance! Will be a big help in my project!

```
$name=$_GET['name']; //input type

$result = mysql_query("SELECT name FROM map");
while ($search = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
$storeArray =  $search['name'];  

if($name!=$storeArray){
echo "<script>alert('Nothing match your voice search! ')</script>";
echo "<script>window.location.href=\"map_index.php?  name='$storeArray'\"   </script>";


}else{


$find=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM map WHERE name='$name'");
while($found=mysql_fetch_assoc($find)){
```

[Click this for the image sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MoCpU.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

First of all mysql has been removed in the most recent version of PHP, so instead use mysqli or PDO: http://php.net/manual/en/intro.mysql.php.

```
<?php
$name = $_GET['name']; //input type

//Create Prepared Statement

if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT name FROM map WHERE name=?")) {
    // bind parameters for markers the first parameter is the type, in this case it is a string, which is why we use 's'. If the parameter was an integer you would use 'i'.
    //if this passes then the name that you are searching the database for exists
    if ($stmt->bind_param("s", $name)) {
      //success
    }
    else { ?>
     <script>
         alert('Nothing match your voice search!');
         window.location.href="map_index.php?name=<?= $storeArray; ?>";
     </script>
   <?php }
} ?>
```

Also note how I separated the script tag and javascript from the php. This will work exactly how you had it, but it is much cleaner and considered best practice.

Comment: sir i can't do it using mysqli because my php is not updated, is there any alternative for that code in mysql? it will really be a big help